# Matplotlib Semilogy says data in negative

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using Matplotlib's semilogy function I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Data has no positive values, and therefore can not be log-scaled.
```

However, my data is all positive in the y-dimension:

```
presvals ~= [1000  990  980  970  960  950  940  930  920  910  900 ... 10]
```

Here is how I am calling the code:

```
import sharppy.sharptab.thermo as thermo
imageScale = 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.5875*imageScale, 6.2125*imageScale))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)
pmax = 1000
pmin = 10
dp = -10
presvals = np.arange(int(pmax), int(pmin)+dp, dp)
tw = []
for p in presvals:
    tw.append(thermo.wetlift(1000., t, p))
ax.semilogy(tw, presvals, 'b-', alpha=.3)
```

I have used this exact code before and it has worked. Is there something that is missing? I have tried formatting the y-axis to no help. Any direction to look at would be appreciated.

Comment: are the values in `tw` all positives? or do you mean `semilogy`?

Comment: It's supposed to be semilogy, which is fixed now, used it for debugging but to no help, so the problem is still valid.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.semilogy(presvals)`  is this working?

Comment: Please see [mcve] and make sure to provide one in your question.

Comment: @xdze2 It did not work, I went ahead and added more code, which is just a pretty standard plotting call.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter how "standard" it is, if it's not runnable (verifiable), you cannot get any help here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did not mean that as a slight to you or StackOverflow at all. I meant it only as a theres not really anything more than a standard setup going on so that shouldn't be an issue. My apologizes for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The point is, *something* must be "non-standard", otherwise you would not get any error. So if the aim is to find out where the error comes from or how to get rid of it, a [mcve], or [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org), is needed.

Comment: For anyone who runs across the problem, I found a temporary workaround with manually constructing the logarithm, and setting the tick labels. But then it came back and started working like the documentation says it should.

Answer (score 0):

for me this code is working:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

imageScale = 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.5875*imageScale, 6.2125*imageScale))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)
pmax = 1000
pmin = 10
dp = -10
presvals = np.arange(int(pmax), int(pmin)+dp, dp)
ax.semilogy(presvals, 'b-', alpha=.3)
```

so I think the problem is in the definition of `tw` which I cannot reproduce...

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, what has worked, although messed up formatting of the plot, is to call a regular ax.plot(prevals) method before calling the semilogy function.